# What are the actual benefits of having a Cognito pool per tenant as recommended by AWS

Tags: authentication, authorization, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant, claims-based-identity

I am trying to decide between a Cognito pool per tenant vs a common Cognito pool for all tenants.

Would love to know what exactly do I get by provisioning by a pool per tenant?

What flexibility a pool per tenant offers that I cannot get through a common pool.